# How to get data from Cube (SSAS) using ADOMD without MDX query..?

Tags: c#-4.0, adomd.net

we have a cube in our project, So far we are accessing cube via Store Procedure (Writing MDX query inside SP and Executing with help of Linked server). Now we have to acccess the cube without MDX query. I have reaserched a lot and found ADOMD where I can get cube information such as Dimension,Attribute and level.ADOMD providers, ADOCommand which executes MDX query and returns result set.Is there any other way to get data from cube without MDX query..?

Answer (score 0):

You can sent MDX, DMX and ASSL-Commands. So its possible to get data without mdx. But what do you want?

With the ADOMD.Net-Objectmodel you get "only" the metadata (also you can get the schemarowsets). For more you need any command.

Comment: I want to read the attributes dataType information & I want to do it for all the attribute in the database. In this case, there is no need to execute any specific MDX query. I read this link (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123475(v=sql.110).aspx) which provides SchemeInformation for the resultSet of a query but not for all the attributes.